# Send a print Screen without saving it

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to send print screens of the server at regular intervals (Say 60ms). At the moment im doing the following.

Use this to capture and save a print screen

```
<?php
    $im = imagegrabscreen();
    imagepng($im, "myscreenshot.jpg");
    imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Then display it

```
<img style="border:1px solid black" class="pos_absolute" id="myimage" src="myscreenshot.jpg" alt="image" width="1360" height="768">
```

But with this method i can get only about 1s update rate. Maybe if i do not save the images i will be able to achieve better refresh rate.. Is it possible to do that?

Thanks

Comment: isn't 60ms too frequent?

Comment: Unless you're trying to record a video or send a stream, it is a bit too frequent.

Comment: Hi...  thanks for getting back to me...

yes i want to send a stream.. I want to send the screen of the server in real time like a video.. that why the 60ms update rate.. Is there a better way to do this??

Comment: If you want to have a realtime remote desktop, you should use some video format with a good compression and send it directly without storing it. Encoding a single 1 MPix image can take 100 - 1000 ms.

Answer (score 0):

Omit the second parameter in `imagepng` - the output will go to the browser:

**yourscript.php**

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
$im = imagegrabscreen();
imagepng($im);
```

Then display it

**theoutput.html**

```
<img src="yourscript.php">
```

It seems that you are limited by time the server needs to process the image and the time the network needs to send the data. You can speed it up by running on some better dedicated server or minimize the network communication.

This is probably all you can do with `imagegrabscreen()`, which is not meant to produce streamed video. You are probably using wrong tool, maybe you could use remote desktop or application like [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/)?

Comment: Hi.. thank you very much for your answer.. But this too take about 1s to update.. Do you know a better way to achieve about 60ms update rate? I want to show the screen of the server inside the browser in real time

Thanks again..

Comment: In that case the image saving is not the bottleneck in your app, see my updated answer.

Comment: Hi thank you very much for your answer. Yes, what i want is to simply show a real time view of the desktop of the server on clients browser. Since i am new to this, i have no idea about how to stream it.. i want to stream both sound and video..

Thank you

Comment: The maybe you [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-networking/sound-while-using-remote-desktop/1d7c5b83-c658-43e6-beab-f91fb243b464) answers your question, together with some [remote desktop recording software](https://www.google.cz/search?q=remote+desktop+recording+software&oq=remote+desktop+recor&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.9482j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)